# Android unbounded ripple and background

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, rippledrawable

it is possible to create a RippleDrawable defining an unbounded ripple and at the same time a background color?
I've tried everything but when i define a shape and its color the ripple is not unbounded anymore.
Also in this page https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.html there is no reference about adding an unbounded ripple over a shape.

I've tried with this layer-list but the result is awful

```
    <layer-list 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <ripple
        android:color="@color/android_l_light_gray">
    </ripple>
</item>

<item>      
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/android_l_dark_gray" />
    </shape>    
</item> </layer-list>
```

this is what i get [image]

Comment: Check selectableItemBackgroundBorderless

Comment: you mean i should add this `style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"` to the button's xml? if yes, it's not working :(

Comment: its not a style, but background:

android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"

Comment: Have you tried using a LayerDrawable?

Comment: @luriiO if i add it as the background then i won't be able to change the background color

Comment: @alanv i've tried.. it doesn't work very well

Comment: Could you add what you've tried for layer drawable and the results to the question?

Comment: @alanv i've just updated the question

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First off keep in mind that `layer-list` drawable works similar to `FrameLayout`, it stacks `item`s as they appear so if you want to have your ripple in front just move it down

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="@color/android_l_dark_gray"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item>
    <ripple android:color="@color/android_l_light_gray"/>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Produces something like

[image: layer list ripple on top]

Now you notice how it gets "clipped" by the other buttons? it is actually being overdrawn, this is because of draw order, the other views' background get drawn on top, not that the ripple is actually getting clipped, so I can think of a few solutions for your particular layout:

a. Get rid of the `layer-list` drawable and use just `ripple` as your button background, use your `shape` or `color` drawable as your `ViewGroup` background, producing:

[image: ripple only]

Notice that you lost your grid like effect due your other background, but take a look at other number pads on lollipop and you will notice they don't have grid dividers, if you still want them use your `ViewGroup` to draw them.

b. Use/draw your ripple as foreground/overlay/drawableTop drawable, and the other one as background, but I think you might run into a similar issue with drawing order as before.

c. Had another one in mind but I just forgot, might come back as a dream ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Check out [Calculator from AOSP](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calculator), you might want to borrow `CalculatorPadLayout` for your grid, or just learn how they do it :)

Comment: hi, thank you :) I already checked the AOSP calculator. They  achieve this result including two different xml file where the first has the dark gray background and the latter has the light gray one.. in both the buttons have the standard ripple background.
It seems that this is the only way to have and unbounded ripple and a striped vertical background

Answer (score 0):

XML

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_key_seven"
        style="@style/AppTheme.KeypadButton"
        android:text="@string/str_one" />
```

STYLE

```
  <style name="AppTheme.KeypadButton" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_ripple_effect_unbounded</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Drawable

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <ripple android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>```

Working awesome for me
````